# Laravel migrate

Tags: laravel, миграция

Я установил **laravel**, мне в архиве отправили 5 миграций (create_user_table) и т.д. Я работаю через **MAMP**. Запускаю **phpMyAdmin**, создаю базу данных. В **.env** в `DB_DATABASE` прописываю название базы, после ввожу `php artisan migrate`.

Получаю вот это:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'operator_service' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = operator_service and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
  at C:\MAMP\htdocs\Users\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:671
    667▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 671▕             throw new QueryException(
    672▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673▕             );
    674▕         }
    675▕
     }
    675▕
  1   C:\MAMP\htdocs\Users\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'operator_service'")
  2   C:\MAMP\htdocs\Users\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct()
```

Ошибку гуглил. Делал `php artisan config:cache; clear`. Нашел вот такое решение: `'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'),`, не уверен, что оно подходит. Подскажите как быть дальше?

Comment: прикрепите ваш .env файл пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте выставить в **.env** эту строку `"DB_HOST"`, вот так:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```